# Adding object from ajax outside of $.when .done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function ajaxCall1(){
    return $.ajax({
        url : 'URL1',
        data : { id : id },
        type : 'GET',
    });
}
function ajaxCall2(item_id)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'URL2',
        data: { item_id: item_id },
        dataType: "text",
        type: 'GET',
    });
}

$.when(ajaxCall1()).done(function(columns){
    $.each(columns, function(column, rows) {
        $.each(rows, function(i, row) {
            $.each(row.items, function(i, item) {
                $.when(ajaxCall2(item.id)).done(function(count){
                    item.counter = count;
                });
                console.log(item);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I would need to get a new object `{counter:count}` from the call into item which is the nested part of object `row`. i do not know how do i actually push the object into the item from `$.when...});`

Comment: are you sure it doesn't? Isn't this just the issue with the asynchronous call you posted yesterday?

Comment: @DaveNewton does this method by using $.when solves the async call? if this is the correct method, and i did a console.log(item) after $.when...});, the object wasn't added into item

Comment: @DaveNewton I've gone through a whole lot of other questions that answers how asynchronous call works and what i had in my mind was this should work. if not, back to the books.

Comment: Without the actual code we'd be speculating.

Comment: You can't access the data after `$.when()` and expect it to be updated yet. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I suspect you need to push each `getData` into an array and use `$.when` on that array so it only fires when ***all*** calls have completed Need to see what `getData()` returns first though

Comment: did an edit to show the full thing. @DaveNewton

Comment: you're still accessing it before the call completes (The log statement, I mean).

Comment: @charlietfl but when i push, i'm still accessing it before the call completes like what Dave said? i suspected it dave but i really hope to know a solution to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about what you need:

```
ajaxCall1().done(function(columns){ // do first ajax

    var promiseArray =[]; // array for promises of subsequent ajax calls
    $.each(columns, function(column, rows) {
        $.each(rows, function(i, row) {
            $.each(row.items, function(i, item) {
                 // each call returns a promise...and also has it's own "done" to update count               
                 var promise =  ajaxCall2(item.id).done(function(count){
                    item.counter = count;
                });
                // push each promise returned from `$.ajax` into array              
                promiseArray .push(promise);                
            });
        });
    });
    // all calls will be completed, can do something with main columns array
    $.when.apply($, promiseArray).done(function(){
        /// do something with columns
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry to be asking this but what does  $.when.apply($, promiseArray).done(){ really mean? i got an error on that. should $ be ajaxCall1?

Comment: it's using `function.apply()` to process the promise array as arguments. Similar to `$.when( promise1, promise2...., promise10)`

Comment: Also it won't fire until all of the promises in the array have resolved

Comment: i'm getting an error on that particular statement and i do not know why.

Comment: but i understood what you just said. a lot of reading on .when

Comment: OK...small ommision, I left out the `function(){` in last `done`....just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting `$.when` to halt execution until it completes, but this is not the case. The execution will continue immediately after `$.when`, and only the callback will be executed when it's done.

If you want a callback for when all of the ajax calls are done, you can add them to an array, and use a final `$.when` on the array of deferreds.

```
var deferreds = [];
$.when(ajaxCall1()).done(function(columns){
    $.each(columns, function(column, rows) {
        $.each(rows, function(i, row) {
            $.each(row.items, function(i, item) {
                var d = ajaxCall2(item.id);
                deferreds.push(d);

                $.when(d).done(function(count){
                    item.counter = count;
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function(){
    console.log( 'All ajax calls are done and each item should have a counter property' );
});
```

Comment: really don't need the first or intermediate `$.when` since `$.ajax` has it's own `done` anyway